# How to save txt file and make two column table using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, multiple-columns, requirements.txt

i am trying to write simple python code for trajectory

```
from numpy import *
from pandas import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from tabulate import tabulate    
y1=int(input("Enter initial height:"))
    v1=int(input("Enter initial velocity:"))
    g=9.8
    t=np.linspace(0,0.2,5)
    yf=y1+v1*t-0.5*(g*t**2)
    print("distance", yf,"Time",t)
    file = open('table.txt', 'w')
    file.writelines = [yf, t]
    file.close()
    print(tabulate([yf, t], headers=['distance', 'Time']))
```

and output is txt file but empty and table appear like this

```
**
                      distance    Time
--  -------  -----  ----------  ------
 2  2.03775  2.051     2.03975   2.004
 0  0.05     0.1       0.15      0.2
**
```

how can i convert it into two columns

i import numpy and

Answer (score 0):

There are extra spaces after first input. I think the best solution is using pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = int(input("Enter initial height:"))
v1 = int(input("Enter initial velocity:"))

g = 9.8
t = np.linspace(0,0.2,5)
yf = y1+v1*t-0.5*(g*t**2)
## make the table
df_trajectory = pd.DataFrame({'time':t,'distance':yf})  
## plot trajectory
plt.plot(df_trajectory['time'],df_trajectory['distance'],'*')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.show()
## export csv (comma delimated text file with header)
df_trajectory.to_csv('output.csv',index=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i want to have table at the end as output. This code is not showing any table in output